# How do I Ignore the build folder in NetBeans 'Find In Projects'?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-6.9

Anyone know how to ignore the build folder when doing a 'Find in Projects' on NetBeans (v6.9.1).

Currently the Search results pane shows all results from src folders but also those from the build folder so if your project contains a lot of JSP files for example, many results are duplicated...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I think I've figured out how to ignore the build folder of projects when doing a 'Find in Projects' in NetBeans 6.9.1:

1. Go to **Tools->Options-Miscellaneous**.
2. Click the **Files** tab.
3. In **Files Ignored by the IDE**, edit the **Ignored Files Pattern**
   regular expression and include the `build` folder. For example, on
   my system I simply added `build` thus:

   ```
   ^(CVS|SCCS|vssver.?\.scc|#.*#|%.*%|_svn|build)$|~$|^\.(?!htaccess$).*$
   ```
4. Click OK to save the options and close the dialog.

(Nerd Note: Took me exactly 1 year to the day to figure this out!)

Comment: I think you have missed out one back slash after 'vssver.?.....it should be:
^(CVS|SCCS|vssver.?\.scc|#.*#|%.*%|_svn|build)$|~$|^\.(?!htaccess$).*$

Comment: @Vin.X That is the default value for this setting. YetMoreStuff merely added `build|` near the middle. I found adding `node_modules` as well greatly sped up the Open File dialog.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to get similar behavior with a multiple node selection search.

- From the 'Files' Window (Found in the Window/Files Menu), expand all
  of your projects and select all of them with a Ctrl+A (PC) or
  Command+A (Mac).
- Then with Control(PC) or Command(Mac) key held down, click the
  folders that you don't want to search.
- Finally, use Ctrl+F(PC) or Command+F(Mac) to open a search, enter the
  text you're looking for, and then choose 'Selection ( # nodes)' under
  the Scope where the '#' symbol is the number of folders you just selected.

It is a little more manual than applying a filter, but you should be able to better control your results.